# Because data.zabbix_template.template has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances

Tags: terraform, zabbix

I'm tring to create a zabbix template with applications defined and trigger.

I can create the template, import my hosts and associate to it.
Now when I try to add the trigger to the template, I receive the error in the object.

this is my
**data.tf**

```
data "zabbix_hostgroup" "group" {
  name = "Templates"
}

data "zabbix_template" "template" {
  for_each = {
    common_simple   = { name = "Common Simple" }
    common_snmp     = { name = "Common SNMP" }
    class_template  = { name = var.class_names[var.class_id] }
  }

  name = each.value.name
}

data "zabbix_proxy" "proxy" {

  for_each = {
  for inst in var.instances :
    "${inst.instance}.${inst.site}" => inst.site
  }

  #host = "zabpxy01.${each.value}.mysite.local"
  host = "mon-proxy1.${each.value}.mtsite.local"
}
```

and this is my **hosts.tf**:

```
# create host group for specific to service
resource "zabbix_hostgroup" "hostgroup" {
  name = var.class_names[var.class_id]
}

# create template
resource "zabbix_template" "template" {
  host = var.class_id
  name = var.class_names[var.class_id]
  description = var.class_names[var.class_id]
  groups = [
    data.zabbix_hostgroup.group.id
  ]
}

# create application
resource "zabbix_application" "application" {
  hostid = data.zabbix_template.template.id
  name = var.class_names[var.class_id]
}

# create snmp disk_total item
resource "zabbix_item_snmp" "disk_total_item" {
  hostid    = data.zabbix_template.template.id
  key       = "snmp_disk_root_total"
  name      = "Disk / total"
  valuetype = "unsigned"
  delay     = "1m"
  snmp_oid="HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize[\"index\", \"HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr\", \"/\"]"
  depends_on = [
    data.zabbix_template.template
  ]
}

# create snmp disk_used item
resource "zabbix_item_snmp" "disk_used_item" {
  hostid    = data.zabbix_template.template.id
  key       = "snmp_disk_root_used"
  name      = "Disk / used"
  valuetype = "unsigned"
  delay     = "1m"
  snmp_oid="HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed[\"index\", \"HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr\", \"/\"]"
  depends_on = [
    data.zabbix_template.template
  ]
}

# create trigger > 75%
resource "zabbix_trigger" "trigger" {
  name          = "Disk Usage 75%"
  expression    = "({${data.zabbix_template.template.host}:${zabbix_item_snmp.disk_used_item.key}.last()} / {${data.zabbix_template.template.host}:${zabbix_item_snmp.disk_total_item.key}.last()}) * 100 >= 75"
  priority      = "warn"
  enabled       = true
  multiple      = false
  recovery_none = false
  manual_close  = false
}

# create hosts
resource "zabbix_host" "host" {
  for_each = {
    for inst in var.instances : "${var.class_id}${format("%02d", inst.instance)}.${inst.site}" => inst
  }

  host = var.ip_addresses[var.class_id][each.value.site][each.value.instance]["hostname"]
  name = var.ip_addresses[var.class_id][each.value.site][each.value.instance]["hostname"]
  enabled = false

  proxyid = data.zabbix_proxy.proxy["${each.value.instance}.${each.value.site}"].id

  groups = [
    zabbix_hostgroup.hostgroup.id
  ]
  templates = concat ([
    data.zabbix_template.template["common_simple"].id,
    data.zabbix_template.template["common_snmp"].id,
    zabbix_template.template.id
  ])
  # add SNMP interface
  interface {
    type = "snmp"
    ip   = var.ip_addresses[var.class_id][each.value.site][each.value.instance]["mgmt0"]
    main = true
    port = 161
  }
  # Add  Zabbix Agent interface
  interface {
    type = "agent"
    ip   = var.ip_addresses[var.class_id][each.value.site][each.value.instance]["mgmt0"]
    main = true
    port = 10050
  }
  macro {
     name  = "{$INTERFACE_MONITOR}"
     value = var.ip_addresses[var.class_id][each.value.site][each.value.instance]["mgmt0"]
  }
  macro {
    name  = "{$SNMP_COMMUNITY}"
    value = var.ip_addresses[var.class_id][each.value.site][each.value.instance]["snmp"]
  }
  depends_on = [
    zabbix_hostgroup.hostgroup,
    data.zabbix_template.template,
    data.zabbix_proxy.proxy,
  ]
}

output "class_template_id" {
  value = zabbix_template.template.id
  description = "Template ID of created class template for items"
}
```

When I run "Terraform plan" I receive the error:

> Error: Missing resource instance key │ │   on hosts/hosts.tf line 26,
> in resource "zabbix_application" "application": │   26:   hostid =
> data.zabbix_template.template.id │ │ Because
> data.zabbix_template.template has "for_each" set, its attributes must
> be accessed on specific instances. │ │ For example, to correlate with
> indices of a referring resource, use: │
> data.zabbix_template.template[each.key]

Where is my error?
Thanks for the support

**UPDATE**
I tried to use

```
output "data_zabbix_template"  {
  value = data.zabbix_template.template
}
```

but I don't see any output when I run `terraform plan`

I tried to modify in:

```
hostid    = data.zabbix_template.template.class_template.id
```

but I continue to receive the same error:

> Error: Missing resource instance key   on hosts/hosts.tf line 27, in
> resource "zabbix_application" "application":   27:   hostid =
> data.zabbix_template.template.class_template.id   Because
> data.zabbix_template.template has "for_each" set, its attributes must
> be accessed on specific instances.
>
> For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
> data.zabbix_template.template[each.key]
>
> Error: Unsupported attribute   on hosts/hosts.tf line 27, in resource
> "zabbix_application" "application":   27:   hostid =
> data.zabbix_template.template.class_template.id   This object has no
> argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "class_template".

**UPDATE:**

```
My script for each host taht I'll add, set two existing template ("Common Simple" and "Common SNMP") and create a new template as below:
  # module.mytemplate-servers_host.zabbix_template.template will be created
  + resource "zabbix_template" "template" {
      + description = "mytemplate-servers"
      + groups      = [
          + "1",
        ]
      + host        = "mytemplate-servers"
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + name        = "mytemplate-servers"
    }
```

Now my scope is to add on this template an application and set two items and one trigger

Answer (score 1):

When you use `for_each` in a data source or resource, the output of that data source or resource is a map, where the keys in the map are the same as the keys in the `for_each` and the values are the regular output of that data/resource for the given input value with that key.

Try using:

```
output "data_zabbix_template"  {
  value = data.zabbix_template.template
}
```

And you'll see what I mean. The output will look something like:

```
data_zabbix_template = {
  common_simple  = {...}
  common_snmp    = {...}
  class_template = {...}
}
```

So in order to use this data source (on the line where the error is being thrown), you need to do:

```
hostid = data.zabbix_template.template.common_simple.id
```

And replace `common_simple` in that line with whichever key in the `for_each` you want to use. You'll need to do this everywhere that you use `data.zabbix_template.template`.